# BroadcastReceiver does not work (with download manager in android)

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I wanted to make my APP listen to download completion action sent by Download Manager and then change VideoView source to play to the newly downloaded video.

My code structure looks like this:

- MainActivity.java : runs UI thread, launches Job Scheduler every 15 minutes to check if there is new video available.
- TriggerJobService.java : starts a new thread to execute the workflow, including downloading new video, resetting VideoView.

I initialize broadcast receiver in TriggerJobService.java

```
public class TriggerJobService extends JobService {
    ...
    public BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete;
    public int downloadFlag = 0;
    public long downloadID;
    ...

    private void downloadFile(String newName) throws JSONException {
        Log.d(TAG, newName);

        String link = "link/to/new/video" + newName;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(link);
        String destName = "v" + newName;

        DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setDescription("Downloading");
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, destName);

        downloadID = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(downloadID));

        onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //Fetching the download id received with the broadcast
                Log.d(TAG, "inside onDownloadComplete");
                long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
                //Checking if the received broadcast is for our enqueued download by matching download id
                if (downloadID == id) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "downloadFile: Successfully downloaded file.");
                    downloadFlag = 1;
                }
            }
        };
      }
    ...
    private void mWorkflow(final JobParameters param) {
        ...
        downloadFile(fileName);
        if(downloadFlag == 1){
            resetVideo(mVideoView, fileNameNew);
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "download failed");
        }
        ...
    }
```

I register broadcast receiver and launch the job service every 15 minutes in MainActivity.java:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scheduleJob();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            TriggerJobService tjs = new TriggerJobService();
            registerReceiver(tjs.onDownloadComplete,
                new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        }
...
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void scheduleJob() {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, TriggerJobService.class);

        JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)
                .build();
        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
        if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed");
        }
    }
```

But I always get the log saying "download failed", which indicates that the receiver never got download complete action from download manager.

P.S.: I have made sure that other parts of my workflow work well.

How do I fix this? Thank you!!

Comment: `launches Job Scheduler every 15 minutes to` You should post that code.

Comment: `new TriggerJobService();` I think you cannot use the new operator to create an instance of a jobservice. Moreover you had already started one. The one for which the code is missing.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks! I have edited my question to post the launching code. And I created an instance of a jobservice to get access to the BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete I create in TriggerJobService class - I read in some tutorials that the broadcast receivers should be registered inside onCreate().

Comment: You can register it from anywhere just before use.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you! But registering it in JobService before use does not work, either.